# Webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin - after babel transform 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack to generate a html file, inside this file I need to have all the javascript inline.

I am using the below configuration, which does generate the html document for me, but it throws an error of

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Looking at the code, it is including some require lines.  I need all the code to be included in the html and not referenced.  can anyone help?

If I remove the "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"] line, then it gives a different error of "regeneratorRuntime is not defined", Googling suggested adding in the plugin line, but that has then caused this other issue?

[image]

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require("fs");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './TestFile/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'TestFile')
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'TestFile.html',
            template: './TestFile/TestFileTemplate.html',
            inject: true,
            testFile: require("@babel/core").transformSync(fs.readFileSync('./TestFile/js/testFile.js', 'utf8'), {
                "presets": [
                    ["@babel/preset-env"]
                ],
                "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
            }).code,
            minify: {
                html5: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributese: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: What is `./TestFile/js/testFile.js` on line `testFile: require("@babel/core").transformSync(fs.readFileSync('./TestFile/js/testFile.js', 'utf8')`? Is it a source file or the output of webpack?